# Xcode error - Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.58.dylib error 134

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, icu

I am trying push a new build of my app, the build process used to work then I started getting this error

```
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 134
```

i tried checking the run script only when installing which helped for my dev builds but not for my archive builds

the app is a detached expo react native app - the full error is this

```
~/Desktop/repticitysingin ~/Desktop/repticitysingin/ios
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.58.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
/Users/waltershub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/repticity-checkin-dyladlpnrkuavlcnilspzxthizjw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/repticity-checkin/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/repticity-checkin.build/Release-iphoneos/repticity-checkin.build/Script-B5722AD01DFB7E3F0084848F.sh: line 6:  7032 Abort trap: 6           PATH="$PATH:$value" exp prepare-detached-build --platform ios
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 134
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue and found the solution here: https://gist.github.com/berkedel/d1fc6d13651c16002f64653096d1fded. Kudos to @berkedel

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node icu4c
brew install node
```

Additionally, another user mentioned that he also had to perform `brew link --overwrite node`, but was not necessary in my case.